# data_for when tag value equals 042

Tags: page-object-gem

I'm using data_magic (0.21) and page-object-gem.
Where I have a yml file marked up as follows:

```
test_1:
  code: 042
test_2:
  code: '042'
```

When I run the following script

```
require 'data_magic'
class MyPage
   include DataMagic
end

page = MyPage.new
puts page.data_for :test_1
puts page.data_for :test_2
```

I'm observing that the value returned from data_for on the test_1/code is not returning 042, rather it is providing 34.
It appears I must prefix the number with single quotes to return the expected.

**Actual**

```
 {"code"=>34}
 {"code"=>"042"}
```

**Expected**

```
{"code"=>042}
{"code"=>"042"}
```

I've read through the code but cannot determine why this is occurring.
Can someone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

I learned that this is expected behavior. A number that starts with 0 is considered octal and the 34 is correct representation.